# facebook javascript sdk method

Tags: facebook-javascript-sdk

I was using facebook javascript sdk method and having a weird behaviour.

Code snippet:

```
FB.api('/me/friends', function(response) {
  friendCount = response.data.length;
  for (i=0; i<friendCount; i++) {
    friendId = response.data[i].id;
    FB.api('/'+friendId, function(response) {
      if (response.birthday)
        resultList.push(new Array(friendId).concat(response.birthday));
      friendCount--;
    });
  }
});
```

I'm expecting a 2d-array of id's of friends who have birthday field defined and their birthday but I'm getting birthdays right but id's are that of last friend in my friend list.
Any idea why this might be happening?

Answer (score 0):

When the the callback function for `FB.api('/'+friendId, ...` is called the value of `friendId` within that callback is the current value of `friendId` when the callback was executed and not the value when `FB.api('/'+friendId, ...` was originally executed. The following should work for you:

```
FB.api('/me/friends', function(response) {
  friendCount = response.data.length;
  for (i=0; i<friendCount; i++) {
    friendId = response.data[i].id;
    FB.api('/'+friendId, function(response) {
      if (response.birthday)
        resultList.push(new Array(response.id).concat(response.birthday));
      friendCount--;
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: Yeah I figured how to fix the problem but I don't get why value of friendId changes when it's defined before FB.api('/'+friendID,...) function..

Comment: Because the innermost callback function is within the scope `FB.api('/me/friends'` with `friendId` and at the time the innermost callback function is called the value of `friendId` is the id of the last friend in your friend list. (I'm probably not explaining this very well).

Comment: Basically, from your perspective, you think multiple copies of the `friendId` are retained for use with each of their respective calls to `FB.api('/'+friendId, function(response) { ... }` - this is not the case. There is only one variable `friendId` maintained and that's the one that is read each time the innermost callback is called.